How do I fill_null on a struct column?
I am trying to compare two dataframes via dfcompare = (df0 == df1) and nulls are never considered identical (unlike join there is no option to allow nulls to match).
My approach with other fields is to fill them in with an "empty value" appropriate to their datatype.  What should I use for structs?
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "int": [1, 2, None],
        "data" : [dict(a=1,b="b"),dict(a=11,b="bb"),None]
    }
)

df.describe()
print(df)

df2 = df.with_columns(pl.col("int").fill_null(0))

df2.describe()
print(df2)

# these error out:...
try:
    df3 = df2.with_columns(pl.col("data").fill_null(dict(a=0,b="")))
except (Exception,) as e: 
    print("try#1", e)


try:
    df3 = df2.with_columns(pl.col("data").fill_null(pl.struct(dict(a=0,b=""))))
except (Exception,) as e: 
    print("try#2", e)


Output:

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬─────────────┐
│ int  ┆ data        │
│ ---  ┆ ---         │
│ i64  ┆ struct[2]   │
╞══════╪═════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ {1,"b"}     │
│ 2    ┆ {11,"bb"}   │
│ null ┆ {null,null} │
└──────┴─────────────┘
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────┐
│ int ┆ data        │
│ --- ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ struct[2]   │
╞═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ {1,"b"}     │
│ 2   ┆ {11,"bb"}   │
│ 0   ┆ {null,null} │
└─────┴─────────────┘
try#1 invalid literal value: "{'a': 0, 'b': ''}"
try#2 a

Error originated just after this operation:
DF ["int", "data"]; PROJECT */2 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"


My, satisfactory, workaround has been to unnest the columns instead.  This works fine (even better as it allow subfield-by-subfield fills).  Still, I remain curious about how to achieve a suitable "struct literal" that can be passed into these types of functions.
One can also imagine wanting to add a hardcoded column as in df4 = df.with_columns(pl.lit("0").alias("zerocol"))

A struct literal to use in the context of pl.Expr.fill_null can be created with pl.struct as follows.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("data").fill_null(
        pl.struct(a=pl.lit(1), b=pl.lit("MISSING"))
    )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬───────────────┐
│ int  ┆ data          │
│ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ struct[2]     │
╞══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ {1,"b"}       │
│ 2    ┆ {11,"bb"}     │
│ null ┆ {1,"MISSING"} │
└──────┴───────────────┘


Good catch.  I hadn't thought to use pl.lit in my various attempts.  That works.

Comparing dataframes with missing values
There is a frame-level pl.DataFrame.equals, which takes a parameter null_equal defaulting to True. It can be used as follows.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [0, 1, None],
    "b": [True, None, False],
})

df.equals(df, null_equal=True)

True


Yes, but unlike df0 == df1 it returns a True/False.  df0 == d1 return a dataframe of bools where each cell is identified as matching or not (True, False and... null for nulls).  I am doing essentially a diff via polars.  equals isn't that useful here.

@JLPeyret Makes sense! I created another answer demonstrating the usage of fill_null with struct dtypes below.
